# Show zero value with ACF from backend to frontend in Bricks builder, Generateblocks and Elementor

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, elementor

Show zero value with ACF from backend to frontend in Bricks builder, Generateblocks and Elementor
Hello, the problem is replicated in everyone and I think it has to do with ACF and its fields, with ACF in the backend in the numeric or text fields, if I fill them with a single zero value, it does not show me anything in the frontend and I What I want is that if I write zero in the field it shows me zero and if I write nothing it shows nothing, how can I solve this error?
This error appears if I use dynamic fields from Bricks builder, Generateblocks and Elementor, with the shortcode `[acf field="field_name" post_id="123"]` works fine, but this shortcode does not work in the wordpress query loop generated by Bricks builder, Generateblocks and Elementor.

Product evaluation example:

`Backend value acf_field = 2  Frontend value = 2/10`

---

`Backend value acf_field = 5  Frontend value = 5/10`

---

`Backend value acf_field = 0  Frontend value =  /10`

It should be like that:

`Backend value acf_field = 0  Frontend value = 0/10`

---

`Backend value acf_field =    Frontend value =  /10`

Thank you so much

```
`function display_zero_if_value_is_zero( $value, $post_id, $field ) {
// Check if the field value is "0" and not empty
if ( $value === '0' && ! empty( $value ) ) {
return '0';
}

    return $value;

}

add_filter( 'acf/format_value', 'display_zero_if_value_is_zero', 10, 3 );`
```

This, like several similar functions, did not work.